# DotNetOpenAuth - Implementing IDirectWebRequestHandler class

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth, provider

We're an OpenId Provider. The server is behind a firewall and so cannot do the RP discovery because there is no direct outbound connection between the Provider and RP. The RP discovery has to go through a proxy.
I read about [DotNetOpenID - Identity Provider behind a firewall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389625/dotnetopenid-identity-provider-behind-a-firewall) and tried to implement IDirectWebRequestHandler as you said. I've pretty much modeled the class after StandardWebRequestHandler. But the GetResponse() function returns an IncomingWebResponse implementation. This class has an internal method GetSnapshot(), and since it is internal, I'm not able to implement this class outside of the DotNetOpenAuth project.
Is there a way around this? Or should I just set the proxy in the web.config like [Specifying a proxy to use with DotNetOpenID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304064/specifying-a-proxy-to-use-with-dotnetopenid)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to implement IncomingWebResponse rather than simply using the one built into DotNetOpenAuth?  You (hopefully) shouldn't need to do any more than just implement IDirectWebRequestHandler itself.

That said, yes, setting the proxy in the web.config file is the advisable and far easier approach.

Comment: What if you want to leave it to the end user to configure the proxy? web.config would then not be considered the "far easier approach" from an end user point of view. I would like to see more answers to this question. ---edit: I see now that tihs is from a server point of view. My problem is not the same